# JmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert() issue with ADT payloads

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to receive a message, synchronously, from a queue using Spring's JmsTemplate. My setup if fairly simple and base on the article [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html). Whenever I call receiveAndConvert() I receive the following error:

> JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT
>   payloads

I know this is related to the process of converting the payload to a instance of an object. However, as you will be able to check below, I've setup Spring datum converter. Also, **sending the message with the same setup works fine.**

The configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd">
    <!-- This job processes transactions in the pending queue and create entries 
        in the processed transactions table. -->

    <!-- Enables communicating with the database -->
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Basic Spring Batch classes -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

    <!-- Beans used by the job -->
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Connection Factory used by the JmsTemplate -->
    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        data-source="dataSource" use-local-data-source-transaction="true" />

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="SPRINGBATCH.PENDING_TRAN_ITEM_QUEUE" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="100"/>
        <property name="messageConverter">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.converter.oracle.MappingAdtMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.oracle.StructDatumMapper">
                        <constructor-arg index="0"
                            value="SPRINGBATCH.PENDING_TRANSACTION_ITEM" />
                        <constructor-arg index="1"
                            value="com.sbe.jobs.createPendingTransactionsAndLoadQueue.PendingTransactionKey" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace and your code that throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out the problem. It seems `JmsTemplate` does not support ADT types, accordingly to this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html):

> custom Advanced Data Type (ADT) (CREATE TYPE xxx AS OBJECT):
>
> > This
> >     payload type **requires a custom message listener container** named
> >     AdtMessageListenerContainer. This listener container also can use a
> >     MessageListenerAdapter with a Oracle AQ ADT specific message converter
> >     specified as MappingAdtMessageConverter. This converter works with an
> >     implementation of the DatumMapper interface. See below for
> >     configuration details.