Dequeue the message from Oracle AQ using Java Sprongboot Listener for Oracle DB 19C version
Following are the dependencies used (Oracle 19C DB version)
com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/19.8.0.0
com.oracle.database.messaging/aqapi/19.3.0.0
and getting the following error message.
Error during JMS connection or Oracle AQ setup: JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads
oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads
I tried changing the dependencies for AQ and not able to resolve it. Please share any working solution. Thanks in advance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398061/jmstemplate-receiveandconvert-issue-with-adt-payloads
